# What makes a pattern in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, pattern-recognition

Assume a stream of characters$(c)$ where $ c \in (A, B, C ... Z)$.

I need to identify patterns available in the stream. As per the definition of a pattern I should be looking for a recurring string.

For example if the stream observed thus far is:

$$A\space B\space A\space S\space Y\space K\space I\space A\space B\space L\space J\space L\space B\space C\space L\space K\space I\space P\space I\space B\space C\space A\space B\space A\space B\space A\space B\space A\space B\space $$

By observation it can be observed that the string $AB$ appears 6 times whilst $BC$ appears 2 times.

My questions are as follows:

1. Apart from repetition are there any conditions that a string should suffice in order to be considered a pattern
2. If repetition is the only factor how many times a string should appear on the stream to be legitimately considered a pattern? Is there any mathematical logic in deciding this factor. (As per my understanding it has to be at least 2 since a single character itself could not be considered a pattern in this case. A single character could also be a pattern if it appears in a fixed interval however, I'm only focused on the string make up at this point.)

Answer (score 1):

1.) In your given string $AB$ and $BC$ are repeating substrings, not patterns. A pattern in a sequence would be a repeating substring that occurs every $n$ characters, where $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  In your given string $AB$ appears after 5 characters, then after 13 characters, then after $0$ characters (3 times); which is not a pattern.  However if you were given the string

$$ A \, B \, D \, L \, N \, A \, B \, R \, O \, D \, A \, B \ $$

$AB$ appears every 3 characters, making that a pattern.

2.) Given my answer to your first question the answer to this question should be pretty straight forward.  Just incase: A substring cannot be considered a pattern unless it is repeated every $n$ characters, where $n \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.  If there is no repetition based on this rule the substring is not a pattern.

I hope this helps! Also, if anyone can expand on this or edit it in anyways please do so.

Comment: Wow answered after 1 year :D However, I think if AB repeats multiple times in a string without the gap it has to be some kind of a pattern too.

Comment: If you have a string $A \, B \, A \, B \, ...$ then yes, the pattern is $A \, B$.  However, if you had $\,A \, B \, A \, B \, D \, P \, O \, A \, B \, Q$ then $A \, B $ would not be a pattern